# Wordpress jQuery is not defined error

Tags: theme-development

Hi I have just learned how to add jQuery to wordpress themes and it works but an error keeps appearing in the wordpress development tool.Here is the code that I posted:

```
    function register_js(){
    if(!is_admin()){
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery' , 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js');
        wp_register_script('quicksand', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/quicksand.js', 'jquery');
        wp_register_script('easing', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/easing.js', 'jquery');
        wp_register_script('custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', 'jquery', '1.0', TRUE);
        wp_register_script('prettyPhoto', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js', 'jquery');


        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        wp_enqueue_script('quicksand');
        wp_enqueue_script('prettyPhoto');
        wp_enqueue_script('easing');
        wp_enqueue_script('custom');
    }

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_js');
```

Not the this is that I used to get the error $ and jQuery is not defined.To solve the $ problem in my main js file I used this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {})
```

Now I am only getting this errors:

```
Error: ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
Source File: http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/01MyWork/js/quicksand.js
Line: 307


Error: ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
Source File: http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/01MyWork/js/easing.js
Line: 39

Error: ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
Source File: http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/01MyWork/js/main.js
Line: 2
```

The scripts seem to work the only problem is that this error is being thrown for every script that I load.How can I solve this?

Comment: have you looked if all your js are included correctly in your page, they appear in the page?
this type of error generaly is when some script you are calling are missing.
maybe jquery-ui is missing, easing.js need jquery-ui if my memory is good

try add a wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui'); after enqueue jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your primary problem is that you are **de-registering core jQuery**. Don't do that. Ever. Period. If you get rid of that, your other scripts will work properly. Just do this:

```
function wpse62373_register_js() {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script('quicksand', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/quicksand.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
        wp_enqueue_script('easing', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/easing.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
        wp_enqueue_script('custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', TRUE);
        wp_enqueue_script('prettyPhoto', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js', array( 'jquery' ) );    
    }

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse62373_register_js' );
```

There are ways to replace core WordPress scripts properly, but I won't facilitate a bad practice such as replacing a core WordPress script by providing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `$deps` need to be an array.

Example:

```
<?php   
wp_enqueue_script('jquerylib', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js');  
wp_enqueue_script('myscript', bloginfo('template_url').'/js/myScript.js'__FILE__), array('jquerylib'));  
?>
```

not

```
<?php   
wp_enqueue_script('jquerylib', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js');  
wp_enqueue_script('myscript', bloginfo('template_url').'/js/myScript.js'__FILE__), 'jquerylib');  
?>
```

like you did.

ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script -> `$deps`

Comment: The problem still persists